# Reacting to answers that don't actually answer the question, but are upvoted by others

Tags: discussion

How should one behave with having their question answered, with answer upvoted by others, but you are not happy with it?

For example, if you ask, "How could you hide an HTML element **without** using jQuery?", and top voted answer is "Just do `$('#element').show()`!". Thank you so much, this answers exactly what I was **not** asking!

This is not the only example. You could have some complex topic question you are interested in, but the one who is answering just ignores the complex part of the question, and answers with something completely unrelated, yet still being upvoted just because you have 1k rep, and that guy who answered has 45k.

The fact answer is upvoted causes virtual community pressure on you for not accepting "such a good answer", and this is very confusing, as accepting answer implies it's helpful and issue is now closed. There is little chance for someone else to give you appropriate answer, because others just skip over your question seeing there is already high–rated, but not accepted answer — it just looks like you are one of those who never tick accept mark, not that answer is horribly invalid, and you, the asker, were the only one who downvoted it, trying to resist avalanche "didn't read lol"–based upvoting.

So, how to resolve these situations gracefully?

Comment: Why would you want to do *anything* without jQuery?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, your comment must now have ~50 upvotes, and question closed for `Not enough jQuery`.

Comment: Best thing is to get in quickly with a downvote and an explanatory comment before the herd votes it up. Also consider emphasising that part of the question if most people appear to have missed it.

Comment: You often know what part is actually missed just after you get the jQuery answer, and then it's already too late to fix anything — you have your question with emphasized part, the unrelated answer and bunch of upvotes.

Comment: I can't remember seeing the situation you describe happen very frequently TBH. I guess you could always put a bounty in that situation to get more eyes on it.

Comment: @MartinSmith, in turn bounties are quite expensive for those who don't have much reputation. Bounty of 50 points is 5% for those who have 1k, and bounty of 500 is less than 0.3% to those having 170k. Bounties are cool, but just not always available, because of reasons.

Comment: I don't actually understand what you are asking, apparently.  If the answer you've been provided doesn't answer your question, say so and/or clarify your question.  Remember, you own the checkmark, if not the community votes. In other news, irony lol (for those of you with 10K who can see my deleted answer... too much coffee today)

Comment: The problem is that enough community votes and no "accept mark" is synonymical to "answer is great, and not accepted because asker had forgot to tick the mark". I wish there was an "unaccept mark" visible to others.

Comment: Over what time period?  Are we talking about 30 minutes after the question was asked, or 30 days after the question was asked?  I don't think there's any expectation of a checkmark during the first day or two that the question is on the site.  That hardly ever happens.

Comment: This - http://superuser.com/q/523169/52178 - question of mine got answered 7 days after initial question, with completely unacceptable solution, getting +4 out of nothing. Correct answer was given only a year after.

Comment: Is this a common occurrence for you, or are you basing this entire question on that single instance?

Comment: No, this is just an example of for how long question with already having answer with "good post" comments and upvotes can be skipped over, until eventually answered correctly. Typically issue I've described arises on much smaller time scale.

Comment: Related to @modchan's suggestion, perhaps if the asker downvotes an answer, a comment should be required, and that comment could be highlighted. I have noticed this issue more than once in even my limited use of SO.

Comment: @modchan a comment that says the answer "doesn't work for me" is the closest we have to an unaccept mark. Use it.

Comment: This problem is also quite prevalent in C++ questions when the asker explicitly wants a low-level way, or an answer provides that (even if including garish blinking exhortations to go for the idiomatic fully-templatised high-level abstractions if possible).

Comment: @KateGregory, this comment yet has to be looked for. Those who blindly vote up jQuery answers just don't read comments - so this does not help, actually. Maybe distinctive indication that asker had downvoted an answer could help? IMHO, asker's opinion can't be treated equally to other's opinion, thus hiding asker's dislike among others "MUCH JQUERY VERY LIKE"s.

Comment: -1 Not enough jQuery. http://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif

Answer (score 20):

Comment on the answer explanining why it is not right for you:

- As I mentioned, I would rather not use jQuery
- I made that change, but I still get the same error message
- I know that would be the solution in 13.0, but as I mentioned I am using 14.0

In addition, you should downvote the answer. Other people may read your question, the answer, and your comment and also downvote the answer. Or they may be inspired to answer, knowing the big +25 is waiting for you to give away still. Either way, your goals are more likely to be accomplished.

Also, consider editing your question. Sure, it's possible the answerer and all the upvoters are poor readers. But it's also possible you didn't make your constraints entirely clear. Don't edit only to "bump", but do be aware that edited questions get on the front page again, gaining more attention. If some time has passed since you asked, a careful improvement and the subsequent bump could garner the extra attention your question needs to get a good answer.

Comment: Not just "can", _please do_ downvote unhelpful answers if it's your question and the answer doesn't help. Help curate the page that spawned from your post.